# Como saber si un mensaje en Discord.js se envió correctamente?

Tags: nodejs, discord.js

Como puedo hacer para ver si un mensaje enviado por un `bot` usando Discord.js se ha enviado correctamente?.

Actualmente hago esto:

```
function enviarmensaje( message ) {
    var generalChannel = client.channels.get( ***** )
    generalChannel.send( message )
}
```

Pero con ese código no puedo manejar los posibles errores que ocurran, hay alguna forma de poder hacerlo como con las promesas?.. ej:

```
var resultado = await enviarmensaje( message );
```

Necesito esto porque cuando el `bo`t envia un mensaje hay veces que falla la conexión a internet y dicho mensaje no se envía.

Lo único que logré hacer, fue captar los eventos no manejados.. pero de nada me sirve si no se cual mensaje fue el que no se envió:

```
0|Sofi  | Rechazo no manejado en: Error: read ECONNRESET
0|Sofi  |     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:162:27)
0|Sofi  | Rechazo no manejado en: Error: read ECONNRESET
0|Sofi  |     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:162:27)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres saber si el mensaje fue enviado,solo debes usar un .then

```
function enviarmensaje(message){
var generalChannel = client.channels.get(*****)
generalChannel.send(message).then(message.channel.send("Correcto"))
}
```